# How to control playback speed of iTunes U lectures in Mac OS?

Tags: itunes, mac, macos, itunes-u

I try to learn swift and opened iTunes U lectures in iTunes on Mac. I wonder how can i change playback speed? It is easy on iPad, but i have no idea how to do this while playing videos in iTunes on Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently not possible in iTunes. I highly recommend you to give [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) about this feature to Apple.

However there is a workaround:

1. Download [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

> VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and
>   framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD,
>   VCD, and various streaming protocols.

2. Right click on the file in iTunes and choose "Show in Finder"
3. Open the file shown in Finder with VLC
4. In the menu "Playback" you can find the "Playback Speed" settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to speed it up, press the fast-forward button (connected two right pointing arrows). It continues to play audio and video, but at 2x-60x speed.

I don't know of any native method for playing at 0.5x, 1.5x, or any other speed slower than 2x.